# The form inside the popup failed to submit the data in magento 2

Tags: forms, magento2.2.6, product-page

I have created a button in product Detail page.
While clicking the button, it will show the popup, the popup contains form.

After filled the details in the form , the submit button is not working while submitting the data in magento 2

Please provide a solution
This is my template which contains script

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">

    <form class="form contact"
          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Us')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
            <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field firstname required">
                <label class="label" for="firstname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('First Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="firstname" id="firstname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('First Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field lastname required">
                <label class="label" for="lastname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Last Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="lastname" id="lastname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Last Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field emailaddress required">
                <label class="label" for="emailaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field mobile">
                <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field extension required">
                <input type='hidden' name="extension" id="extension-name"
                       class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" id='customer-contact' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>"
                        class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function (
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                title: 'Contact Form',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click', function () {
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please check what is the action url of the form. "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>

Comment: yes . I have checked. The submit button is irresponsive. It does not work

Comment: I Uesd below xml and it working fine for me,

Comment: which xml did you used

Comment: ../layout/catalog_product_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>              
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="mypopup.form"               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/popup_form.phtml"
                 />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: Can u shar ur template file for reference

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: Hi using custom block for this . My submit button not working
Kindly help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps as describe below. It Works for me.

I assume you are using a custom theme name "Vendor_theme"

**step 1 )** create the file **catalog_product_view.xml** under ***/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/***

File :  **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>        
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addtocart"/>                       
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="mypopup.form"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/popup_form.phtml"
                 />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2 )**  Create the file **popup_form.phtml** under ***/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/***

Please chnage Form action url (i.e 'http://www.yoursiteurl/routename/controllername/actionname')

File : **popup_form.phtml**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">

    <form class="form contact"
          action="http://www.yoursiteurl/routename/controllername/actionname"
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Us')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
            <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field firstname required">
                <label class="label" for="firstname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('First Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="firstname" id="firstname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('First Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field lastname required">
                <label class="label" for="lastname"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Last Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="lastname" id="lastname" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Last Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field emailaddress required">
                <label class="label" for="emailaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field mobile">
                <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field extension required">
                <input type='hidden' name="extension" id="extension-name"
                       class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" id='customer-contact' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>"
                        class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function (
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                title: 'Contact Form',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click', function () {
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

**Step 3:** Run Below Command to clear static files and flush cache

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]